# Show multiple entities/forms on same page with Backpack\CRUD

Tags: laravel-backpack

We are evaluating Backpack for Laravel. One missing thing, a showstopper, that we can't find, is, how we can display multiple entities on the same page.

Examples:
- List of persons, i click one person (an action button), and then it routes to a page, where one can edit the persons details, below the edit form show a list of all the person's pets. If I click one of the pets, then below it shows a form where one can edit the pets data.

- Two lists, left the "Machines" list, on the right a "Parts" list. If i click a "Machine" item, then it loads it's "Parts" on the right.
- Three Tabs, the first shows a detail view of a "Person" entity. The second tab shows a list of the person's friends (also Person entities), the third shows the list of the person's cars.

Is anything like this possible using Backpack for Laravel? Is there a way to include a whole list, or edit form, an action of an entity in a blade template?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this? Was there another crud library that's better suited?

Comment: We didn't find an inbuilt solution for this task. We agreed with our UX expert, that we can solve those cases by other workflow structures, or to build those form/list combinations manually in the rare cases where we can't solve it by other workflows. I have not been involved in the project afterwards, and haven't yet touched backpack again. So I don't have a clear answer to this.